# Palindrome program works fine for a single test case but keeps taking input otherwise

Tags: java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int test_cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (test_cases >= 1 && test_cases <= 20) {
            String[] ans = new String[test_cases];
            for (int i = 0; i < test_cases; i++) {
                char[] n = br.readLine().toCharArray();
                int k = 0;
                int j = n.length - 1;
                while (k <= j) {
                    if (n[k] == n[j]) {
                        k++;
                        j--;
                        ans[i] = "wins";
                    }
                    else
                        ans[i] = "loses";
                }
            }
            for (String s : ans)
                System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
    }
}
```

PROBLEM STATEMENT: The first line of the input contains an integer T, the number of testcases. This is followed by T lines containing an integer N. For each input output "wins" if the number is a palindrome and "loses" if not, in a new line.

For test_cases=1, the program works fine but for test_cases>1 the program keeps taking input. I have solved the palindrome problem but I still can't understand what is wrong with this code. Can anybody explain to me why does it keeps taking input?

Comment: **You really shouldn't swallow exceptions**, like `catch (Exception x) { }`. If something goes wrong, you can see *what* goes wrong and fix it.

Comment: Running locally, the code works fine - the first line is the number of test cases, and then your program inputs that many sequences and only after taking all of them prints outs "wins" or "loses" for eah one.

Comment: The loop `while (k <= j)` is infinite if the entered number is not a palindromve, even if you enter 1 (one) for the number of test cases.

Comment: Since Java 5, the preferred way to get input from the user in a console program is via class [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: @Abra I used BufferedReader instead of Scanner because I read somewhere that there are faster. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non palindrome, your code runs in infinite loop. Just add break for that.

```
while (k <= j) {
    if (n[k] == n[j]) {
        k++;
        j--;
        ans[i] = "wins";
    }
    else {
        ans[i] = "loses";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int test_cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if (test_cases >= 1 && test_cases <= 20) {
                for (int i = 0; i < test_cases; i++) {
                    char[] n = br.readLine().toCharArray();
                    int k = 0;
                    int j = n.length - 1;
                    boolean flag=false;
                    while (k <= j) {
                        if (n[k] == n[j]) {
                            k++;
                            j--;
                            flag=true;
                        }
                        else{
                            flag=false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag)    System.out.println("wins");
                    else    System.out.println("loses");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
        }
    }
```

For a string which is not a palindrome, your loop runs infinitely.
Also, you need not store the results in an array for all the test cases, you can print it every time for each test case. However, if you intend to store strings and display results later, you can use something like StringBuffer classes.